# Uncaught SyntaxError when get address info from google map api

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3, jsonp

I want to get bounds information  by using ajax to send url to google, but I get an Uncaught syntax error at the at the data, so I always get alert. But if I use geocode to get that address info, it works.So, my question is, how could I get more info from it, what's wrong with my ajax function and how should I fix it?
Thanks for any help.

```js
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initMap() {


   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center : {
     lat : 23.53016,
     lng : 118.79706
    },
    zoom : 7
   });

  }
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var geocoder;
   var myLatLng;
   var allLatlng = [];
  

   $("#btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var input_address = $("#text_address").val();
    var requesturl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=&&address="+input_address;
    
    $.ajax({"type":"GET","url":requesturl,"dataType":"jsonp","contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",})
    .done(function(datas){
        for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
            var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
            alert(adress);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
     alert("Sorry, something wrong here");
    });
    
       geocoder.geocode({
           'address': input_address
       }, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               myLatLng = {lat:results[0].geometry.location.lat(),lng:results[0].geometry.location.lng()};
               allLatlng.push(myLatLng)
results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat;
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatLng,
             map: map,
             title: 'Hello World!'
           });
           } else {
               alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
       });
       

    //  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound    
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = allLatlng.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
      //  And increase the bounds to take this point
      bounds.extend (allLatlng[i]);
    }
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds (bounds);
   });//end click
   
  });
 </script>
 <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">
  
 </script>
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position:fixed;
}

div#map{
  position:fixed;
  left: 50%;
  height:100%;
  width: 50%;
}
div#left{
 width:50%;
 overflow:scroll;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
 <form id="address_form">
   <input id="text_address" type="text" name="address"
    placeholder="input your address here" autofocus />
   <button type="submit" id="btn">Search</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using the client side JS API services?

Comment: Hey friend, could you explain me more deeper?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see it..., thank you!